# create a button in excel sheet to add a column with a heading given by a user

Tags: excel, vba

I  tried to create  a button to add columns in a excel sheet and column header should get from the user after submitting the response column should be added in the given name. I tried it with the macros

```html
Dim x As Variant
    Dim ColumnNum%
    x = InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    ColumnNum = x
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).Insert shift:=xlRight

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum - 1).Copy

    'THe line above doesnt make any sense whatsoever. 
     'Im not going to try and trouble shoot it but it seems like you dont understand how to
     ' properly scuplt things. Youll notice i changed how you strucutred the .copy part. 
     'THe part that doesnt make sense to me is the Range section. 
 
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).ClearContents
```

this is the code i used  and i'm not aware about VB is there any way to get the column name from the user when clicking the button?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google sheets. Please delete the tag .

Comment: The code is `vba`, not `vb6`, please change the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

```
Dim colName As Variant
colName = InputBox("Enter Column Name", "Input Column Name")

If StrPtr(colName) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("canceled")
ElseIf colName = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("didn't type anything!")
Else
Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("E1").Value = colName
End If
```